# have errore to BUILD telegram android source

Tags: android, android-ndk, telegram

this is a warning:

> WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
>   android.useDeprecatedNdk
>   NdkCompile is no longer supported
>   Affected Modules: TMessagesProj

and after the run, have this error:

> Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process H:\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=H:\Telegram-master\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=H:\Telegram-master\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=H:/Telegram-master/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/afat/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=H:\Telegram-master\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\afat\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}

and this:

> process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
>   H:/sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/add-application.mk:178: *** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear about what is wrong and what you need to do. What happened when you did that change?

Answer (score 1):

This may be caused by your local `gradle.properties` configuration.

To fix this I removed the line `android.useDeprecatedNdk` from `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`